# How to resize in flutter with flexible

Tags: flutter, resize

I'm using flexible to make it responsible

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          //Creating timer for white side
          Flexible(child: TimerBox(WhiteSideColor, WhiteSideRotation),),

          //Creating buttons in the middle
          Flexible(child: SizedBox(child: ButtonsInTheMiddle(),)),

          //Creating timer for black side
          Flexible(child: TimerBox(BlackSideColor, BlackSideRotation)),
        ],
      ))
    ],
  ),
); 
}
```

And I want to make it like this picture below, but **i can't resize the Flexible widget** in the middle, I tried sizedbox and FractionallySizedBox. And thanks in advance for helping.

PD: I draw some green/blue (i can't tell the color) line boxes arounds that is the size I want to make for the widgets

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the flex factor to each Flexible widget to decide what it's size will be compared to the other Flexible widgets.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html

Comment: Yeah it worked, I tried before but I didn't fully read how it works. Thanks <3 !!!
https://imgur.com/qMZSAdb

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if I really understand. Do you want to make the middle button has some size? If you want a specific size, use SizedBox to give a height and width, and in its child pass your desired size. If not, use flex factor to Flexible

Comment: Yeah i ended using flex thanks to Yair, It was my bad for not fully reading how flex works, thanks for your interest.
imgur.com/qMZSAdb